# Using sep_apply in a semax context with VST

Tags: verifiable-c

Nika Pona asked this question on vst-user, and I have the same question:

I have a goal of the form `semax _ PROP()LOCAL()SEP(a;b;c;d)` and a lemma of the form `a*c |-- k` or `a*c = k`.  How do I get form SEP(a;b;c;d) to SEP(k;b;d)?

I've fiddled around with the `sep_apply` tactic but so far I've failed to get it to apply in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sep_apply` should work, but you may need to fully instantiate the arguments of the lemma, e.g.,   `sep_apply (my_lemma a c k)`

Comment: I've narrowed down my problem to the following goal: `forall A B P, (!!P && B) |-- FF -> A * (!!P && B) |-- FF`.  after `intros A B P H.`, then `sep_apply H.` fails with `No applicable tactic`.  The problem seems to be due to the inclusion of the proposition !!P.  I'm not sure if this is an expected limitation of `sep_apply`, or a bug, or I'm using an outdated version of VST.

Comment: I've followed up on the above at https://github.com/PrincetonUniversity/VST/issues/580